# Halt function execution based on stop signal

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, electron

I was wondering if there is a way to immediately halt (exit) a function while it executes when I receive a signal.

Currently the signal is sent via `ipcMain` where `ipcRenderer` is listening to said stop signal, although I'm not sure how or if it is possible to stop a function's execution when signal is received.

Example:
`startThis()` is called, ipcRenderer starts listening, `run()` is called.

```
startThis() {
    ipcRenderer.on(`stopTask-${taskId}`, (event, msg) => {
            console.log("STOP SIGNAL")
            helpers.sendTaskUpdate(taskId, msg);
            return; // Supposed to halt execution of "run()"
        })
    run() // more functions is called in here too.
}
```

Would I need to place the listener inside of `run()`? Any help is appreciated, thank you.

`run()` is a series of sequential (async) requests.

Comment: You might have the `run` functions check a flag which is set when `STOP` is received. Hard to say exactly without seeing what `run` is like

Comment: `run` is a series of sequential async requests so for example when a request is completed, a promise is fulfilled and then another function is called, so forth.

Comment: Check the flag at the beginning of each request, and if the flag was set by the stop signal, don't continue

Comment: Yep, that could be an option - I was wondering if there's a less tedious way

Comment: I don't think that would be tedious at all, it's the most straightforward way I can think of, and would require very few lines (but it's hard to post an exact answer without seeing more of the code)